# How to filter data from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Hi I have below array in my application. I want to make three lists on basis of this array.

```
[ 'type addPet {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type createUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type createUsersWithArrayInput {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type createUsersWithListInput {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type deleteOrder {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type deletePet {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type deleteUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type findPetsByStatus_items {\n  id: String\n  category: findPetsByStatus_items_category\n  name: String\n  photoUrls: [String]\n  tags: [findPetsByStatus_items_tags_items]\n\n  # pet status in the store\n  status: String\n}',
  'type findPetsByStatus_items_category {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}',
  'type findPetsByStatus_items_tags_items {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}',
  'type findPetsByTags_items {\n  id: String\n  category: findPetsByTags_items_category\n  name: String\n  photoUrls: [String]\n  tags: [findPetsByTags_items_tags_items]\n\n  # pet status in the store\n  status: String\n}',
  'type findPetsByTags_items_category {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}',
  'type findPetsByTags_items_tags_items {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}',
  'type getInventory {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type getOrderById {\n  id: String\n  petId: String\n  quantity: Int\n  shipDate: String\n\n  # Order Status\n  status: String\n  complete: Boolean\n}',
  'type getPetById {\n  id: String\n  category: getPetById_category\n  name: String\n  photoUrls: [String]\n  tags: [getPetById_tags_items]\n\n  # pet status in the store\n  status: String\n}',
  'type getPetById_category {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}',
  'type getPetById_tags_items {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}',
  'type getUserByName {\n  id: String\n  username: String\n  firstName: String\n  lastName: String\n  email: String\n  password: String\n  phone: String\n\n  # User Status\n  userStatus: Int\n}',
  'type loginUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type logoutUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type Mutation {\n  addPet(body: param_addPet_body): addPet\n  updatePet(body: param_updatePet_body): updatePet\n  updatePetWithForm(petId: String, name: String, status: String): updatePetWithForm\n  deletePet(api_key: String, petId: String): deletePet\n  placeOrder(body: param_placeOrder_body): placeOrder\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value. Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors\n  deleteOrder(orderId: String): deleteOrder\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  createUser(body: param_createUser_body): createUser\n  createUsersWithArrayInput(body: param_createUsersWithArrayInput_body): createUsersWithArrayInput\n  createUsersWithListInput(body: param_createUsersWithListInput_body): createUsersWithListInput\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  updateUser(username: String, body: param_updateUser_body): updateUser\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  deleteUser(username: String): deleteUser\n}',
  '# Pet object that needs to be added to the store\ninput param_addPet_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  '# Created user object\ninput param_createUser_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  '# List of user object\ninput param_createUsersWithArrayInput_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  '# List of user object\ninput param_createUsersWithListInput_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  '# order placed for purchasing the pet\ninput param_placeOrder_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  '# Pet object that needs to be added to the store\ninput param_updatePet_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  '# Updated user object\ninput param_updateUser_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type placeOrder {\n  id: String\n  petId: String\n  quantity: Int\n  shipDate: String\n\n  # Order Status\n  status: String\n  complete: Boolean\n}',
  'type Query {\n  viewer: viewer\n}',
  'type updatePet {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type updatePetWithForm {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type updateUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}',
  'type viewer {\n  # Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings\n  findPetsByStatus(status: [String]): [findPetsByStatus_items]\n\n  # Muliple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.\n  findPetsByTags(tags: [String]): [findPetsByTags_items]\n\n  # Returns a single pet\n  getPetById(petId: String): getPetById\n\n  # Returns a map of status codes to quantities\n  getInventory: getInventory\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other values will generated exceptions\n  getOrderById(orderId: String): getOrderById\n  loginUser(username: String, password: String): loginUser\n  logoutUser: logoutUser\n  getUserByName(username: String): getUserByName\n}' ]
```

In this array I want to make three lists. One list contains

```
type Mutation {\n  addPet(body: param_addPet_body): addPet\n  updatePet(body: param_updatePet_body): updatePet\n  updatePetWithForm(petId: String, name: String, status: String): updatePetWithForm\n  deletePet(api_key: String, petId: String): deletePet\n  placeOrder(body: param_placeOrder_body): placeOrder\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value. Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors\n  deleteOrder(orderId: String): deleteOrder\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  createUser(body: param_createUser_body): createUser\n  createUsersWithArrayInput(body: param_createUsersWithArrayInput_body): createUsersWithArrayInput\n  createUsersWithListInput(body: param_createUsersWithListInput_body): createUsersWithListInput\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  updateUser(username: String, body: param_updateUser_body): updateUser\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  deleteUser(username: String): deleteUser\n}
```

Second list contains

```
type viewer {\n  # Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings\n  findPetsByStatus(status: [String]): [findPetsByStatus_items]\n\n  # Muliple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.\n  findPetsByTags(tags: [String]): [findPetsByTags_items]\n\n  # Returns a single pet\n  getPetById(petId: String): getPetById\n\n  # Returns a map of status codes to quantities\n  getInventory: getInventory\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other values will generated exceptions\n  getOrderById(orderId: String): getOrderById\n  loginUser(username: String, password: String): loginUser\n  logoutUser: logoutUser\n  getUserByName(username: String): getUserByName\n}
```

and third list should contains exclude below items, should have rest of the items of the above array.

```
type Query {\n  viewer: viewer\n}
type viewer {\n  # Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings\n  findPetsByStatus(status: [String]): [findPetsByStatus_items]\n\n  # Muliple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.\n  findPetsByTags(tags: [String]): [findPetsByTags_items]\n\n  # Returns a single pet\n  getPetById(petId: String): getPetById\n\n  # Returns a map of status codes to quantities\n  getInventory: getInventory\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other values will generated exceptions\n  getOrderById(orderId: String): getOrderById\n  loginUser(username: String, password: String): loginUser\n  logoutUser: logoutUser\n  getUserByName(username: String): getUserByName\n}
type Mutation {\n  addPet(body: param_addPet_body): addPet\n  updatePet(body: param_updatePet_body): updatePet\n  updatePetWithForm(petId: String, name: String, status: String): updatePetWithForm\n  deletePet(api_key: String, petId: String): deletePet\n  placeOrder(body: param_placeOrder_body): placeOrder\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value. Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors\n  deleteOrder(orderId: String): deleteOrder\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  createUser(body: param_createUser_body): createUser\n  createUsersWithArrayInput(body: param_createUsersWithArrayInput_body): createUsersWithArrayInput\n  createUsersWithListInput(body: param_createUsersWithListInput_body): createUsersWithListInput\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  updateUser(username: String, body: param_updateUser_body): updateUser\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  deleteUser(username: String): deleteUser\n}
```

Does anyone know how to do this in javascript ?

Comment: Please re-format your data structure. It is really difficult to get what you want to achieve

Comment: @FiriceNguyen I did it. can you check it now

Comment: So you have an array of string which literally exact like that ?

Comment: Yes. I want to extract data from the array into three list. I described what should be in all three list in question. I dont know how to filter it, new in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the array. Get the type string using regex. Get the relevant array from the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) `r`, and push to the array. Return `r` (the accumulator). When reduce is done, use [Map#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to get an array of arrays, and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to separate variables.

```js
const data = ["type addPet {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type createUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type createUsersWithArrayInput {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type createUsersWithListInput {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type deleteOrder {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type deletePet {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type deleteUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type findPetsByStatus_items {\n  id: String\n  category: findPetsByStatus_items_category\n  name: String\n  photoUrls: [String]\n  tags: [findPetsByStatus_items_tags_items]\n\n  # pet status in the store\n  status: String\n}","type findPetsByStatus_items_category {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}","type findPetsByStatus_items_tags_items {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}","type findPetsByTags_items {\n  id: String\n  category: findPetsByTags_items_category\n  name: String\n  photoUrls: [String]\n  tags: [findPetsByTags_items_tags_items]\n\n  # pet status in the store\n  status: String\n}","type findPetsByTags_items_category {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}","type findPetsByTags_items_tags_items {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}","type getInventory {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type getOrderById {\n  id: String\n  petId: String\n  quantity: Int\n  shipDate: String\n\n  # Order Status\n  status: String\n  complete: Boolean\n}","type getPetById {\n  id: String\n  category: getPetById_category\n  name: String\n  photoUrls: [String]\n  tags: [getPetById_tags_items]\n\n  # pet status in the store\n  status: String\n}","type getPetById_category {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}","type getPetById_tags_items {\n  id: String\n  name: String\n}","type getUserByName {\n  id: String\n  username: String\n  firstName: String\n  lastName: String\n  email: String\n  password: String\n  phone: String\n\n  # User Status\n  userStatus: Int\n}","type loginUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type logoutUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type Mutation {\n  addPet(body: param_addPet_body): addPet\n  updatePet(body: param_updatePet_body): updatePet\n  updatePetWithForm(petId: String, name: String, status: String): updatePetWithForm\n  deletePet(api_key: String, petId: String): deletePet\n  placeOrder(body: param_placeOrder_body): placeOrder\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with positive integer value. Negative or non-integer values will generate API errors\n  deleteOrder(orderId: String): deleteOrder\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  createUser(body: param_createUser_body): createUser\n  createUsersWithArrayInput(body: param_createUsersWithArrayInput_body): createUsersWithArrayInput\n  createUsersWithListInput(body: param_createUsersWithListInput_body): createUsersWithListInput\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  updateUser(username: String, body: param_updateUser_body): updateUser\n\n  # This can only be done by the logged in user.\n  deleteUser(username: String): deleteUser\n}","# Pet object that needs to be added to the store\ninput param_addPet_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","# Created user object\ninput param_createUser_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","# List of user object\ninput param_createUsersWithArrayInput_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","# List of user object\ninput param_createUsersWithListInput_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","# order placed for purchasing the pet\ninput param_placeOrder_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","# Pet object that needs to be added to the store\ninput param_updatePet_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","# Updated user object\ninput param_updateUser_body {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type placeOrder {\n  id: String\n  petId: String\n  quantity: Int\n  shipDate: String\n\n  # Order Status\n  status: String\n  complete: Boolean\n}","type Query {\n  viewer: viewer\n}","type updatePet {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type updatePetWithForm {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type updateUser {\n  # default field\n  empty: String\n}","type viewer {\n  # Multiple status values can be provided with comma separated strings\n  findPetsByStatus(status: [String]): [findPetsByStatus_items]\n\n  # Muliple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.\n  findPetsByTags(tags: [String]): [findPetsByTags_items]\n\n  # Returns a single pet\n  getPetById(petId: String): getPetById\n\n  # Returns a map of status codes to quantities\n  getInventory: getInventory\n\n  # For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10. Other values will generated exceptions\n  getOrderById(orderId: String): getOrderById\n  loginUser(username: String, password: String): loginUser\n  logoutUser: logoutUser\n  getUserByName(username: String): getUserByName\n}"];

const [arr1, arr2, arr3] = [...data.reduce((r, row) => {
  const [typeStr] = row.match(/^type\s[^\s]+/i) || [];
  const subArr = r.has(typeStr) ? r.get(typeStr) : r.get('other');
  
  subArr.push(row);
  
  return r;
}, new Map([['type Mutation', []], ['type viewer', []], ['other', []]])).values()];

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is trivial ... or I didn't get the request

```
const array = [...]

const list0 = [], list1 = [], list2 = []
for(const row of array) {
  if(row.indexOf('type Mutation') === 0)
    list0.push(row)
  else if(row.indexOf('type viewer') === 0)
    list1.push(row)
  else if(row.indexOf('type Query') === -1)
    list2.push(row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it by text content, you can use the array filter function from javascript, and match text occurence (case insensitive). This is a very basic example (not tested):

```
var list1 = GetMatchingEntries("type Mutation");

function GetMatchingEntries(matchingText){
    return yourArray.filter(function(textEntry){
              return textEntry.toUpperCase().indexOf(matchingText.toUpperCase()) !== -1;
           });
}
```